# Transparancy on image not working together well with box-shadow

Tags: css, web, photoshop, shadow

So I've been trying to add a shadow to my images and I've been encountering some issue.
The images used are PNG of cut out products but they have a round border so there's still some transparent corners as seen here:

This is my image in Photoshop:

[image: Image in Photoshop]

Now if I add them on my site and put a box-shadow on top of them this is the result:

[image: Image on website]

There's this white-grayish corners that look pretty bad. Is there any workaround for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the image itself, not the shadows, that white-grayish corners are part of the image and you can't do nothing with css to fix it, what you need to do is import your image again from photoshop without that corners.